# Unable to add Splunk plugin as a datasource to Grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, splunk

I have added Splunk plugin on my Grafana cloud Pro account.
Trying to configure datasource in the grafana

Data source => add datasource => Splunk

with `url- http://<hostname>:8000`
with basic authentication `user and password`.

But after clicking 'add & test' it gives following error

```
Post "http://<splunk host domain name>/:8000/services/auth/login": dial tcp: lookup <splunk host domain name> on 10.188.192.10:53: no such host
```

Grafana automatically appends /services/auth/login to the url rather it shoud search for /account/login

Please suggest me required actions...

Comment: It appears from `lookup <splunk host domain name> on 10.188.192.10:53: no such host` to be a DNS problem.  Verify you have the correct Splunk host name.

Comment: `/services/auth/login` is the correct path to use as this is an API login rather than an interactive login.

Comment: Yes, domain name is correct. If I hits  "http://<host domain name>:8000"  from browser , it takes me to the Splunk login page.

Comment: Domain name is correct only in your browser. But Grafana machine (container) is not able to resolve it.

Comment: If the domain name is correct then ensure Grafana is using a DNS server that can resolve the name.  Alternatively, resolve the name yourself and replace `<splunk host domain name>` with the IP address.

Comment: Got the reason, this is happening because my splunk datasource is available on vpn only. Although my local machine is on vpn but grafana cloud account is not. So grafana is unable to locate Splunk instance.

Comment: Solutions- on premise Grafana installation is required with License / make splunk IP public.